# Angular 2 Renderer2 - how it works

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-directives

I'm trying to understand the necessity of adding the renderer2 decoration in directives or in component in angular 2.

from documentaion :[renderer 2 documentaion](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) 
they do not provide example that hoe it works. can anyone explain with full example.please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Renderer2` is just an abstraction.
If you use Universal (server-side-rendering) or WebWorkers, there is no DOM available and code that accesses the DOM directly will just cause an exception.

If you use `Renderer2`, Angular can provide different implementations using its dependency injection functionality, to make your code use an implementation that is compatible with the platform the code is currently running on.

`Renderer2` is quite limited, because all methods only allow to update the DOM, but none allows to **read** any information from the DOM.
If you actually need to read you need to take special measures to make it work with Universal or WebWorker (for example check the current platform and skip the execution of code that directly accesses the DOM if it's not the browser platform, or use others provided by the current platform)