# Query Dom element (DIV id or class) In Angular but without @ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to query a dom element in Angular, I can't use @ViewChild decorator as the html is rendered through another widget. So I want to do something like:

```
let target = document.querySelector(".domelement");
target.style.width = "100%";
```

I would wrap this in a function and implement it in the onInit method.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below in angular way. Direct access to DOM is not suggested in angular

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {  Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';

...

 constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.renderer.setStyle(this.document.querySelector(".domelement"), 'width', '100%');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why is direct access to DOM not suggested in Angular?

Comment: With this approach we can prevent XSS attacks and can develop cross platform application where document object is not available. This is the good link which explains it better 
https://www.ninjadevcorner.com/2019/04/dom-manipulation-using-angular-renderer2.html. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995018/angular-2-renderer2-how-it-works.